# JPA ManyToMany problem

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Hello i have an Entity `Exam`

```
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;
    .....
    ......

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Exam> exams;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="id")
    private List<Exam> parentExams;
```

The problem is that

```
@ManyToMany
        private List<Exam> exams;
```

is ok works great...

but this doesnt validate?!

```
 @ManyToMany(mappedBy="id")
        private List<Exam> parentExams;
```

Any idea what to do ?
I just want to get the exams that are parents of the current exam.

Διεθνές Νομισματικό Ταμείο

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.

mappedBy="id" should be 
mappedBy="exams"